# Looking for Lubuntu 20.04 User Manual

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, documentation

I'm looking for the Lubuntu **20.04**-specific manual, and I can't find it anywhere. Any help appreciated.

Comment: FYI:  As @Terrance said in comment on the first answer, Lubuntu has it's own infrastructure (*even if parts are owned by Canonical (web addresses) so as to prevent issues like have happened in the past, like all flavors it's under flavor control*) thus sites such as https://lubuntu.me/links/ can allow you to reach members & other users quickly. Yes they have people allocated to check various sites (*eg, now*) but if asked on a site where Lubuntu members are around you'll have the chance of faster responses

Answer (score 7):

@Terrance provided the latest link

- https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/

The word *stable* in that link/URL refers to the latest *stable* release; thus is the Lubuntu 21.10 manual.

The ***lts*** manual can be found at

- https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/

ie. it's just the word *stable* replaced with a *lts* so you can view the *latest* LTS manual instead of latest *stable* (non-LTS) manual.

*Terrance noted that changing the link of the URL can be problematic in some browsers (using the same `firefox` I use too) so it may require you to copy & paste the link in a new tab; make change in the address line then press enter to view the page. The comments are currently viewable below this answer.*

Comment: FYI:  If you want to view the latest we have; replace the *stable* or *lts* with *master*...

Comment: Just don't try to replace the word `stable` with `lts` after you have already opened it or you will pull your hair out.  ;)  It kept changing it back to `stable/lts` on mine and UGH!  I had to open it in a new tab for it to work right.  +1

Comment: :)   It works for me, and I do it very often.. but the results may vary on the browser that you're using..    The way this [stable/lts/master/..] works is common with other Ubuntu projects/doco (as I recall it was a Canonical/Ubuntu person who suggested it as a means for manual version control, but we had many *standards* to choose from..)

Comment: Well I was doing it in Firefox for me. So I'm thinking when I get home here I'm going to go ahead and delete my answer because yours is way better than mine. :-) and I'm honestly not here just for upvotes so it's all good with me I think your answer is is great. :-)

Comment: I'm using `firefox` too... maybe I get better reactions as my firefox history already has entries for `manual.lubuntu.me/lts` & `manual.lubuntu.me/stable` ... thus you're experiencing what more readers of this site will get rather than what I see.  Yeah the 'upvotes', &'awards/achievements' on this site really feel like *spam* (*annoying distractions*) to me...

Comment: Excellent answer. `/lts` gets me there whether pasted or typed over `/stable`. I use Librewolf by the way.